# fputc can't handle large files? Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, malloc, fwrite

I have a Problem using fputc - maybe someone can help.
I have allocated some storage at the beginning and assigned on data[0] = 'B' and data[1] = 'M' - the rest of the array is filled with numbers. Then the data will be written in a .bmp-File:

```
//this scenario works

unsigned long *data;
data = malloc(55);

data[0] = 'B';
data[1] = 'M';

data[2] = 34;
data[3] = 0;
.
.
.
data[55] = 0;

unsigned long long i;
FILE *output;

output = fopen("output.bmp", "wb+"); 
if(output==NULL) {
    printf("ERROR writing files!\n");
}

 for( i = 0; i < 55; i++)               
 {                                          

    fputc(data[i], output);
 }

 fclose(output);
```

The rest (data[2] - data[55]) is filled with numbers. When I write the data into a .bmp file everything works (in this example i generated a blue 1px). Now if I want a bigger .bmp file, for example:

```
//this scenario doesn't work

unsigned long *data;
data = malloc(300000);

data[0] = 'B';
data[1] = 'M';

data[2] = 34;
data[3] = 0;
.
.
.
data[300000] = 0;

unsigned long long i;
FILE *output;

output = fopen("output.bmp", "wb+"); 
if(output==NULL) {
    printf("ERROR writing files!\n");
}

 for( i = 0; i < 300000; i++)               
 {                                          

    fputc(data[i], output);
 }

 fclose(output);
```

The following error occurs:

> Segmentation fault: 11

I figured out, that the last size of malloc, where it works is malloc(130000) - all after that doesn't work.
Has anyone any idea, how i can get rid of this problem?

I also tried changing fputc to fwrite - failed.

Thanks a lot!
Greetings

Comment: very first thing - check the return value of malloc

Comment: `unsigned long *data;
data = malloc(N);

data[0] = 'B';
data[1] = 'M';

.
data[N] = 0;`  --> Wrong allocation size.  Instead `data = malloc(sizeof *data * (N + 1));`

Comment: In case of out of memory, `malloc` may return NULL. Could you write directly after the `malloc` a guard, something like `if ( NULL == data ) { fprintf( stderr, "malloc failed\n" ); exit(1); }

Comment: I did check malloc with this code:
    if(!data) {
        free(data);
        return 0;
    }

There didn't came any failure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is wrong, cos it needs 300,000 * sizeof(long) bytes, but you only allocate 300,000 bytes

```
unsigned long *data;
data = malloc(300000);
```

I think you need (since you seem to be writing bytes)

```
unsigned char *data;
data = malloc(300000);
```

or (less likely)

```
unsigned long *data;
data = malloc(300000 * sizeof(long));
```

Comment: OP's `data[300000] = 0;` implies a larger allocation needed.  OTOH, `data[300000] = 0;` itself is not needed.

Comment: ah yes, i missed that last line. So needs malloc(300001)